# simpleITK with anaconda python

Tags: python, itk, simpleitk

I am trying to install simpleITK on my macbook which has mavericks running on it. I have installed Anaconda python.

When I try to import SimpleITK as sitk, I get the following error

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Users/dagarshali/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SimpleITK-0.8.0.post29-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/SimpleITK/**init**.py", line 1, in 
    from .SimpleITK import *
  File "/Users/dagarshali/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SimpleITK-0.8.0.post29-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/SimpleITK/SimpleITK.py", line 28, in 
    _SimpleITK = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/dagarshali/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SimpleITK-0.8.0.post29-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/SimpleITK/SimpleITK.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_SimpleITK', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/dagarshali/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SimpleITK-0.8.0.post29-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/SimpleITK/_SimpleITK.so, 2): Library not loaded: libpng15.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/dagarshali/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SimpleITK-0.8.0.post29-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/SimpleITK/_SimpleITK.so
  Reason: image not found

Not sure how to fix this problem.

Any suggestions?

Best regards,
Vishwa

Comment: Better post on sitk and/or anaconda bug sites or forums. Unfortunately, many things are tested under linux and then fail under mac.

Comment: Had the same frustrating problem a while ago... I had to remove anaconda (completely remove), then reinstall SimpleITK.
I suggest you to not use the operative system python, the one under /System/Library/Frameworks/Library.framework/Versions/blabla, but to download a new python from https://www.python.org/downloads/, that will go under /Library/Frameworks/Library.framework/Versions/blabla.
Even better, use virtualenvironments. (in both cases to me worked only with anaconda out of the way).

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing here that you compiled SimpleITK yourself and have conflicting libraries for Anaconda and the system.

Binaries for the Anaconda distribution are now available in Binstar:
https://binstar.org/simpleitk

Answer (score 0):

It was built using an older version of limping
On your virtual environment, try to downgrade libpng:

```
conda install libpng=1.5.13
```